# How to render a WebUserControl client-side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, callback, webusercontrol

I created a web user control which has some ASP.NET and third-party controls.

I've already tested my control in the markup of a page and it works well.

```
<APP:MyControl ID="myControl1" InitializeWithValue="Employee" />
<APP:MyControl ID="myControl2" InitializeWithValue="Supplier" />
```

Now, I want to render this control in the same page but not when the page renders at the first time. In fact, I will click a button which will call a callback and in that moment I want to render the control.

I was trying to do something like this.

```
void ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
   MyControl c1 = new MyControl();
   c1.InitializeWithValue = Person.Enum.Employee; //<--CRASH

   System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
   HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
   c1.RenderControl(hw);
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then on my client-side receiver

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="testcallback('', '')">Test</a>
<div id="divControls"></div>

<script>
    function receiver(arguments, context) {
        document.getElementById('divControls').innerHTML = arguments;
    }
</script>
```

But it crash at the moment of the initialization because all the inner controls of the WebUserControl are null. They have not been initialized.

This is the property of the control

```
   [Browsable(true)]
   public Person.Enum InitializeWithValue
   {
      get { return this.enumPersonValue; }
      set
      {
         this.enumPersonValue = value;
         //Literal control
         this.litPersonType.Text = "Employee"; //<-- CRASH because litPersonType is null.
      }
   }
```

Some can help me to correct this or suggest me another way render a web control but client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserControls usually are tighted to the Page Life Cycle, so you would need to recreate a whole page and render it instead.

Second, you should load your usercontrol using its .ascx file and not only its class, this is required because only your class is not enough.

You can still try to do like you was doing only creating but using `Page.LoadControl`:

```
void ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
   MyControl c1 = (MyControl)page.LoadControl("/Controls/myControl.ascx");
   c1.InitializeWithValue = Person.Enum.Employee; //<--CRASH

   System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
   HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
   c1.RenderControl(hw);
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

But if your control has Events related to the Page Life Cycle you might need to create a whole context to it:

You can do it all like this:

```
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
       using (var page = new Page())
       {
            MyControl myControl = (MyControl)page.LoadControl("/Controls/myControl.ascx");

            var head = new HtmlHead();
            page.Controls.Add(head);

            var form = new HtmlForm();
            page.Controls.Add(form);

            var div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div.ID = "myControlContent";
            form.Controls.Add(div);

            div.Controls.Add(myControl);

            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, stringWriter, false);

        }
        return stringWriter.ToString()
}
```

Then in your JS you can parse the whole html and get only the innerHTML of `div#myControlContent`, for example:

```
function receiver(arguments, context) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(arguments, "text/html");

    document.getElementById('divControls').innerHTML = doc.getElementById('myControlContent').innerHTML;
}
```

note that [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Browser_compatibility), is available only in mordern browsers, but you can find other approachs for older browsers...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now with the LoadControl I can manage the control properly, but what if my current page that will hold the control is a page which is contained inside a MasterPage.Master and I don't want to recreate everything.

Comment: Forget my question. I transfered my Page_Load inside my control and I call it directly in a private method. I was trying to control the Page.IsPostBack which doesn't make sense anymore. It works. Thanks.

Comment: I applied the first way you recommended, but do you know how to resolve the rendering of Telerik controls? I got the Exception: "Script control 'dateInput' is not registered script control...'. I'm just using a RadDateTimePicker inside my WebUserControl, nothing special. I'll continue looking into this, but maybe you know how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess that their Control uses some events of the Page which owns it, to do their stuff but as your control isnt in a Page, such Events Handlers are not triggered and thus do not do their work, like registering scripts controls...